# ImportError: cannot import name 'Mimir' from 'mimir'

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I get the error below if I try to import mimir

'from mimir import Mimir'

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.10 /Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/RandomProjects/venv/mimir_code.py 

Sys path:  ['/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/RandomProjects/venv', '/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python310.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages']


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/RandomProjects/venv/mimir_code.py", line 14, in <module>
    from mimir import Mimir
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mimir' from 'mimir' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mimir/__init__.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Tried to add the correct path. Also create a new environment but didn't work. Issue seen with only mimir and not other packages

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, did you install the package as an administrator?

For me packages don't work unless installed with administrative privileges.

Just run cmd as admin and do `pip install mimir`

Comment: I'm using Mac Apple M1 Pro running Ventura. I've installed mimir using pip

The package path is included in the sys path as well. So not sure what the issue is

Sys path:  ['/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/RandomProjects/venv', '/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python310.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages']